# Add HTTP Header to NSURLRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, nsurlrequest

Is there any way to add HTTP header to `NSURLRequest` object? I used to add them in `NSMutableURLRequest` using:

```
[request addValue:@"PC" forHTTPHeaderField:@"machineName"]
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I don't think you can modify the HTTP Headers of a `NSURLRequest`. I think you're trying to modify a `NSURLRequest` object that you didn't initialize?

You could create a `mutableCopy` of your request and then set the header fields with the following method:

```
 -(void)setValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field.
```

After that you can `copy` the mutable request back onto your `NSURLRequest` variable.

**EDIT**: Added example below

```
/* Create request variable containing our immutable request
 * This could also be a paramter of your method */
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"]];

// Create a mutable copy of the immutable request and add more headers
NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [request mutableCopy];
[mutableRequest addValue:@"Hless" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-user-nick"];

// Now set our request variable with an (immutable) copy of the altered request
request = [mutableRequest copy];

// Log the output to make sure our new headers are there    
NSLog(@"%@", request.allHTTPHeaderFields);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the thing is you can't add Http Headers to the NSURLRequest you can only get them, to be honest i wanted to use NSURLRequest because i wanted to receive a chunked file using the the delegate "didReceiveData" but now i am using threads instead with NSMutableURLRequest.

Comment: I know it's been a while since I posted this, but due to somewhat popular demand I updated the answer for correctness and added an example.

Comment: hey @Hless I tried this method but I'm still getting unauthorized. Can you see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342728/sending-httpheaderfield-for-nsurlrequest-in-afmultipartformdata

Comment: Or just create an NSMutableRequest from the start because you expect to add a header.

Comment: @AlexZavatone Based on the question and OP's comment I'm guessing he recieved a NSURLRequest from another library or so. So in that particular case he wouldn't be able to use a NSMutableRequest from the start. He also states in his question that he knows how NSMutableRequest works.

Answer (score 9):

Already answered (and thanks to those answers), but here's a more simple example:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setValue:@"es" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
```

Comment: If you read the question it's actually not. OP states that he knows how a NSMutableURLRequest works. If you want to modify an existing NSURLRequest that you did not initialize in your own code (e.g. from a library), you will have to use the method in my answer, or you'll lose the headers etc from the original request.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://10.28.79.63:3000/testing";

NSMutableURLRequest *imageRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[imageRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[imageRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

[imageRequest setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"content-Type"]; 
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:[imageData length] + 512];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

//Here u adds the Headers which will be posted in body 

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; content-type: application/octet-stream; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"inLove.mp4\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[imageRequest setHTTPBody:body];
NSURLConnection * theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:imageRequest 
                                                delegate:self];
```