# Use 'loadRequest' instead of 'loadHTMLString'?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

How do I convert the following to use 'loadRequest' instead of 'loadHTMLString'?

I need to add a HTTP header and the only way I have found is to use loadRequest with a NSMutableURLRequest as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265123/add-http-header-to-nsurlrequest).

```
myHTMLContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<head>%@</head><body>%@</body>", @"<link href='styles.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>", htmlFromPrevVar]; 

    NSString *myPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSURL *myBaseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPath];

    [self.myUIWebView loadHTMLString:myHTMLContent baseURL:myBaseURL];
```

Comment: Why would you need to add a HTTP header to a `loadRequest:` that is coming from the file system? Do you want to actually load the HTML from a network resource (i.e. a web page?)

Comment: @race_carr The variable titled htmFromPrevVar that gets concatenated to the html has a a path to an image that requires an oAuth bearer token in the authorization header. When you load the html we can see the authentication error on the server.

Comment: Ahh, interesting. So you want to craft a local HTML string, which has an `<img>` tag in it that requires an OAuth header? And you need some way to load the local html (via file or in-memory) via a NSURLRequest so you can add the authentication header.

Comment: @race_carr Exactly. That's the issue I'm fixing with the iOS application. The picture will not load if the authorization header with the oAuth bearer token is not included. I'm working on a solution based on what Matt said, but it's not pretty and a the bit slow.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer, were you able to solve this issue ? Please share. I am having the same issue.

Comment: @ParthoBiswas This was more than 3 years ago, I hardly remember writing this, but I did mark matt's answer below as the answer, thus I'm sure it had something to do with it. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the string to a file and give the URL of that file in your request.

Comment: Can you please explain why we need to do that ?  Is there any better way to handle such situation ?  @matt